# Detecting which version of L3 programming layer is in use

Tags: tex-core, expl3

The LaTeX3 package I am writing uses `\prop_gput_from_keyval` which has been introduced in `2021-05-16` of `expl3`.
I am trying to guard my package against users of older TeX installations.
In order for them to be confronted with an informative error message,
I want to abort loading with something I've seen around here, like so:

```
! LaTeX3 Error: Mismatched LaTeX support files detected.
(LaTeX3)        
(LaTeX3)        The L3 programming layer in the LaTeX format
(LaTeX3)        is dated 2021-02-18, but in your TeX tree the files require
(LaTeX3)        at least 2021-05-16.
```

Is there an interface for this error message?

Of course, I have `\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2021-05-16]` which checks the version of the LateX2e format but it only issues a warning not an error.
So I could do something like `\IfFormatAtLeastTF` to branch into a `\PackageError`, however, this only reads the LaTeX format date while what I need to guard against is the L3 programming layer date in `\ExplLoaderFileDate`. In particular, I need to check if the `expl3` version is recent enough.
I could do

```
\IfPackageAtLeastTF{expl3}{2021-05-16}
{
    % Package version new enough
}{
    \PackageError{MyPackageName}
        {The L3 programming layer in the LaTeX format
        is dated \ExplLoaderFileDate, but in your TeX tree the files require
        at least 2021-05-16.
        }
}
```

which feels odd to have to handcraft this LaTeX3 error message. Also this wouldn't work for LaTeX versions older than 2020-10-01.
So should I first check the LaTeX version with `\IfFormatAtLeastTF` which I can escape with

```
\providecommand\IfFormatAtLeastTF{\@ifl@t@r\fmtversion}
```

and then the `expl3` version with `\IfPackageAtLeastTF`?

I've read the discussion in [this github issue](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/186) and it seems that the LaTeX team suggests that rather than checking for a release date to better check if a control sequence exists via something like this

```
\cs_if_exist:NTF \prop_gput_from_keyval:Nn { TRUE } { FALSE }
```

But this feels not very natural because now I need to somehow keep track which features of `expl3` I use. If, in the future, I use another newer feature, I need to manually add or replace the `\cs_if_exist` for each new control sequence I am using.

Is there an interface that package authors can use to protect users of older installations by invoking the LaTeX3 error message above? I guess I'm asking for something like
`\NeedsExplVersion{2021-05-16}` or `\IfExplAtLeastTF{2021-05-16}{TRUE}{FALSE}` but throwing an error rather than a warning.

Comment: you can not really guard users against this error. They get it if their format has been created with a different version of expl3 and the only solution is to throw an error and to force the user to recreate the format (or to remove stray local formats).

Comment: Sorry, I might have miscommunicated: I have had users that got a non-descript 'missing \begin{document}' error. The reason was that they had an old expl3 version. I want my package to check if expl3 is older than 2021-05-16 and if so, then I want to throw the LaTeX3 error. 
What is the recommended way of doing that? 
Should I check if the control sequence ```\prop_gput_from_keyval:Nn``` exists (and update this for any newer feature I'm using) or should I check if the ```expl3``` date by the method described in my post (checking Format date, then Package date and handcrafting error message)?

Comment: see https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/1004